# android download ways, what's difference between socket, downloadmanager, http?

Tags: android

1. I have try socket, but feels not so efficiency or healthy.
2. Which one suits me, I need resume broken downloads. What is good and bad about them?
3. Is http or socket based on tcp? I can code by myself, but I don't know much about download-manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `DownloadManager` should always be the best solution for long-running downloads. It manages network connectivity, task suspending/resuming and removal for you. In other words, you almost needn't worry about anything. Additionally , it's fairly easy to use and understand. You can search an example for detail usage.

If you use socket or http directly, you will have many things(and of course, a lot of coding work) to deal with .

Comment: thanks,can i ask a simple question?can DownloadManager resume broken downloads or pause in my views?

Comment: I have no idea for " resume broken downloads" but it can pause a task.You can try the preinstalled Download manager app because it internally uses `DownloadManager` service